# circle divided by two css with image

Tags: html, css, image, geometry

How to divide circle into 2 parts, which can be rgb or url image? 
which looks like
[image]

so I wrote code which works just with rgb, but I don't know how it can be with url image... please help me:

```css
.divided-circle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient( 135deg, #26A0DA 50%, #d92550 50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.5px solid #9b9b9b;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="divided-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want two images or a color and image?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it can be both, like both sides are images; and one side is image and other side is color; and both sides are colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:red;  /* first background */
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800) center/cover; /* second background */
  /* adjust the below angle to control the rotation */
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(60deg,#fff 49.8%,transparent 50%);
          mask:linear-gradient(60deg,#fff 49.8%,transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

With CSS variables to easily control:

```css
.box {
  --a:65deg; /* angle of rotation */
  /* first background */
  --b1:red;
  /* second background */
  --b2:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800) center/cover;
  
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:var(--b1); 
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
  background:var(--b2); 
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(var(--a),#fff 49.8%,transparent 50%);
          mask:linear-gradient(var(--a),#fff 49.8%,transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--b1:blue;--b2:linear-gradient(red,yellow);--a:135deg;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--b1:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1014/800/800?grayscale) center/cover;--b2:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1014/800/800) center/cover;--a:180deg;"></div>
```

Comment: @Daniyar added another version with variables

Comment: thank you man) you helped me.. this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip-path` for this:

```css
.overlap1 {
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.overlap2 {
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<img class="overlap1" src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-png-1.png"/>
<img class="overlap2" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/avatar-369-456321.png"/>
```

More on `clip-path` [here](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#the-new-clip-path).

Comment: what about img? is it can be a div with background?

Answer (score 0):

You can `border-radius` this way, and inside the divs you can image or text ...

```css
.divided-circle{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.divided-circle .left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:  100% 0% 0% 100% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border: 0.5px solid #9b9b9b;
  border-right: none;
}

.divided-circle .right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #212121;
  border-radius: 0% 100% 100% 0% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 0.5px solid #9b9b9b;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="divided-circle">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```